# How can I display all products from all categories on one page with woocommerce?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

[BlissCBDWorld.com/store](http://BlissCBDWorld.com/store)

I have a shop landing page that lists all of the categories (don’t mind the rudimentary photoshopped products, I’m changing that ). What I want to do is also have a button that will display all products.

So my question is, how can I get all products from all categories to display all in the same page? I want to keep the uniform woocommerce structured look, like the other category pages have, if possible.

Is there an easily solution woocommerce short code maybe?

I haven’t spent a great amount of time trying to figure this out yet but I figure you guys always know best!

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use shortcodes. Follow this link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use the Product Table plugin to display all products on a single page in an organized way more like a bulk order form. It would be easier and time-savvy for the customers to search for products, select quantity or variants, and Add to cart by just staying on the same page. 
Here is the guide to implement bulk order on WooCommerece. 
https://codup.co/design-woocommerce-bulk-order-form/

Have a look and do let me know if you have further question regarding it

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I actually achieved this by creating and assigning a secondary “All Products” category to all of my products, then linking to that category page from my main categories page. with filters and sorting options. 

Thought I’d share how I solved this. Thanks again!